# list directory name of symbolic link

Tags: 14.04, grep, ls

I am trying to find all the symbolic links on my system with name `keytool`. I use the below command :

```
ls -lR | grep keytool
```

It gives some results, but i want the directory names as well. So i use the -d option:

```
ls -ldR | grep keytool
```

But this gives me no results at all. This is probably because of the behaviour of -d option as described by `--help` :

```
-d : list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links
```

So how do i get the directory names of the symbolic links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use find

Note: after some testing, the only way I found was to pipe the output to xargs and test the output of find

```
find / -name keytool -type l | xargs -L1 --null bash -c 'if [ -d $0 ]; then echo $0 ; fi'
```

Comment: Why not just use the built-in action `-ls` instead of `-exec ls -l {} \;`?

Comment: That returned me nothing

Comment: Now i get the error `find: paths must precede expression: c
`

Comment: that returned me nothing as well..wierd

Comment: well, run `find / -name keytool` , the listing will show all matches. I am guessing none are both directories and symlinks

Comment: you are right. `find / -name keytool` did return me 1 result, which is neither directory or symlink. `find / -name keytool*` returns me all required results.